# How to remove high ridges on concrete flooring

Tags: concrete

I ripped up the carpet in my basement and I have some good curling (*approx 3/8”*)that I need to fix before I lay down new flooring.

I Looked at renting a wet grinder from HD but they are immensely heavy and getting that into my basement would be impossible. I looked at dry grinding but apparently the dust is extreme, I thought about creating a dust tent.

I Contacted a few guys to see if they would do this, but service is terrible and seems companies don't want business.

I am Just checking in here  for  other ideas.

What’s the best way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Curling?  You mean High seams or high spots. I.E. not flat.? Somebody will "want business" That is why they are in business. Are you putting down something other than carpet?

Comment: Laminate flooring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a angle grinder with a carbide block / diamond impregnated masonry grinding wheel.

the concrete can be kept damp with a spray bottle to limit the airborne dust, make sure to use a GFCI protected receptacle or extension cord when working with power tools and water.

This method will make a slurry that is cleaned up with a sponge and water.

Your high spots don’t look that severe and could be cut down with a 4-1/2” grinder.
The wheels cost for a 4-1/2” grinder run from 40-100$ I find these are better for surfacing than abrasive disks those don’t work as well with water but can be used it will take a few and as these get smaller it is easy to create divots where the wheels stay the same size. Of corse a larger grinder like a 9-1/2” with a larger wheel will be easier, faster and less chance if divots but cost more

A 4-1/2” Grinder can do this at a reasonable cost even if you need to purchase a GFCI extension cord so you can keep the concrete damp and eliminate the dust.